# The difference between size and capacity of matrix in igraph

Tags: matrix, igraph

In igraph, we can use `igraph_matrix_size` to get the size of a matrix, and we can use `igraph_matrix_capacity` to get the capacity of a matrix, but who can tell me what is the difference between them?

Thank you. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`igraph_matrix_capacity` shows the number of elements that matrix can potentially have without doing a relocation.

More details in the [documentation](http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html):

> 3.11.3. igraph_matrix_size — The number of elements in a matrix.
>
> `long int igraph_matrix_size(const igraph_matrix_t *m);`

http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph_matrix_size

Compared to:

> 3.11.4. igraph_matrix_capacity — Returns the number of elements allocated for 
>   a matrix.
>
> `long int igraph_matrix_capacity(const igraph_matrix_t *m);`
>
> **Note** that this might be different from the size of the matrix (as
>   queried by `igraph_matrix_size()`, and specifies how many elements the
>   matrix can hold, without reallocation.

http://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph_matrix_capacity

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I just found out that I made a mistake about the difference between capacity and size,but I understand now.Thank you again.